# Why is current-density a vector?

Tags: electric-current, vectors, density

I was told that current has a direction but does not follow vector-laws, so it is a scalar quantity. That's okay. I thought it through Kirchoff's junction law: *assume two currents joining at 90 deg, but they will not add vectorially, but algebraically.*

Now, I am told that current density is a vector quantity. Solving for this, *two current densities maybe added at 90 deg or 45 deg they will definitely give same result and will definitely not add vectorially.*

So, why is current-density considered as vector?

$$i = j A$$
$i$ is current,
$j$ is current-density, and
$A$ is the area of cross-section

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90995/25301

Comment: Dividing scalar by scalar doesn't yield vector, I don't really know nor understand what's going on. I don't think I can be of any help to you at the moment, but if I ever find anything soon, I'll post. Good luck pal.

Comment: @TechDroid thnx for help :) but as much i know, cross-section area is vector quantity..

Comment: That shows how much more I need to learn. You're welcome by the way. But what's the direction element of cross-section area?

Comment: @TechDroid perpendicular to the surface

Comment: @TechDroid you can have 2 directions for each surface, but there are conventions for different cases

Comment: @TechDroid you can understand it like this, a rectangle with sides as l vector and b vector has area l × b (vector product) or b × l

Comment: That's just not in my sphere of thinking at all. Thanks.

Comment: @TechDroid try this, this is fascinating to learn, it also confused me when i learned them first in gauss's law httpss://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14165/221932